# How can I have new fullscreen mac windows open next to the current window?

Tags: macos

I finally figured out how to stop fullscreen windows from moving to the first space when I open a new program in fullscreen mode (System Preferences -> Mission Control -> uncheck "Automatically rearrange spaces based on most recent use"). But now when I open a new window in the same program (e.g when opening a new Chrome window, the new window opens in the last space rather than in a new space next to the current window).

How can I make new fullscreen windows open next to the current window, just to the right of it?

Comment: Was this ever resolved? This is driving me crazy as well

Comment: @Joe the Person Not yet unfortunately...

Comment: Same. When we have spaces for different types of jobs/roles/tasks, we open different apps in each space (we normally assign apps to open on each space), but sometimes a space has more activity and we need to open some of the apps/docs Full Screen. Then we expect the apps to be opened next to the desktop it was already opened in. It made so much sense as I could change from the desktop to the FS related apps very fast and conveniently. I was amazed by how well thisl was organised, but then I found this FS windows opened at the end precisely when the desktops have a fixed place? No solution yet?

Comment: There's a sort of workaround here:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259610/how-to-make-fullscreen-windows-appear-next-to-the-current-space-with-rearran 
but still, it would be much faster and clear to have them open next to the desktop it was already open. As least as an option.

Comment: I've posted a better workaround in the same link above (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259610/how-to-make-fullscreen-windows-appear-next-to-the-current-space-with-rearran), in case it is useful for you too

Answer (score 0):

The option you are disabling (Systems Prefs -> Mission Control -> Automatically Rearrange Spaces based on most recent Use) is what gives you your requested functionality. With this enabled, if you open a new "full-Screen" app, it will create the space (right) adjacent to the one you are working in.

It functions in the same way "alt/cmd + tab" works. Your most recently visited application/focused window will always be the (right) adjacent option.

It is possible that there is 3rd-Party "Mission Control-esq" apps out there that may give you your requested functionality, but I don't believe its possible with stock macOS

Comment: "Automatically Rearrange Spaces" almost sorta resolves this, but at the terrible cost of spatial memory: nothing that goes out of view is ever where you remember it being. IMO, combining LRU with a spatial navigation task is one of the worst UX ideas ever (Visual Studio, pre-VSCode, only had LRU keyboard nav for tabs). Most modern web browers either default to or have an option for what I believe is the desired behavior: open new tabs adjacent to the current one.

Comment: agreed with @JohnWhitley, enabling "Automatically Rearrange Spaces" it's terrible.